# not able tot detect phisycal door or other big rectangle in open cv android

Tags: android, opencv

I wrote code to detect rectangles in open cv. And i am able to detect few object but i am not able to detect physical door or big rectangle. Please check my code and correct me if i am wrong somewhere . Another problem is this code is not able to detect rectangle constantly so when i draw rectangle it comes and go , comes and go and it looks bad. Any way to detect regularly in every frame.

```
 Mat  output= getGray(inputFrame.rgba(),inputFrame.rgba());
        Imgproc.medianBlur(output, output, 5);
        Imgproc.erode(output, output, new Mat());
        Imgproc.dilate(output, output, new Mat());
         Mat edges = new Mat();
        Imgproc.Canny(output, output, 5, 50);
//      Vector<MatOfPoint> vector=new Vector<MatOfPoint>();
//      Imgproc.findContours(output, points, output, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
         contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        contours.clear();
        Imgproc.findContours(output, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

 MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
        rgbImage=inputFrame.rgba();
        mDrawnContours.clear();

> Blockquote

 for(int i=0;i< contours.size();i++){
            MatOfPoint tempContour=contours.get(i);
            MatOfPoint2f newMat = new MatOfPoint2f( tempContour.toArray() );
            int contourSize = (int)tempContour.total();
            Imgproc.approxPolyDP(newMat, approxCurve, contourSize*0.15, true);
            MatOfPoint points=new MatOfPoint(approxCurve.toArray());

            if((Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(tempContour))<100) || !Imgproc.isContourConvex(points)){
                Log.i(TAG, "::onCameraFrame:" + " too small");
                appendLog("Too small");
                continue;
            }
            else if(points.toArray().length >= 4 && points.toArray().length <= 6){
                int vtc = points.toArray().length;
                Vector<Double> cosList=new Vector<Double>();
                for (int j = 2; j < vtc+1; j++){

                    cosList.add(angle(points.toArray()[j%vtc], points.toArray()[j-2], points.toArray()[j-1]));

                }   
                   double mincos = getMin(cosList);
                   double maxcos = getMax(cosList);
                   Log.i(TAG, "::onCameraFrame:" + "mincos:"+mincos+"maxcos:"+maxcos);
                   if (vtc == 4 && mincos >= -0.1 && maxcos <= 0.3)
                   {
                       mTotalSquare++;

                        Imgproc.drawContours(rgbImage, contours, i, new Scalar(0,0,255));
                        DrawnContours contours2=new DrawnContours();
                        contours2.setIndex(i);
                        mDrawnContours.add(contours2);
                        Log.i(TAG, "::onCameraFrame:" + "found");
                        appendLog("found");

                   }
                   else{
                       Log.i(TAG, "::onCameraFrame:" +" not found " +"mincos:"+mincos+"maxcos:"+maxcos);
                       appendLog("not found 1");
                   }

            }

return rgbImage
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: what do you detect so far ?

Comment: Hi, i could detect small papers, keboard, laptop screen , small cover, sometimes hitter but not able to detect bigger object.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, that large contours have more than 4 edges. Their contour consists of large number of short line segments (depends on approximation function parameter in line

```
 Imgproc.approxPolyDP(newMat, approxCurve, contourSize*0.15, true);
```

).

And you have condition which check for edge numbers:

```
points.toArray().length <= 6
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply. I removed that condition but it did not make much difference. Another problem is i am not getting rectangle in every frame. So rectangle comes and go so frequently it does not look good.

Comment: Ok, I can get you another idea: you get contour, calculate the area of the contour, then use minAreaRect method, and compute the area of min enclosing rectangle. If your contour shape close to rectangular, the areas will be approximately equal. Hope you catch the idea.

Comment: HI Andrey, Thanks for your email but some how i am not able to understand what you are saying. if possible can you please provide some code snippts so i can understand better.

Comment: Area1=Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(tempContour)); RotatedRect RR=minAreaRect(contourPoints);Area2=RR.size.width*RR.size.height; if(fabs(Area1-Area2)<someSmallTreshold) then contour is close to rectangle shape.

Comment: HI, Following is my code for your suggetion but it seems it seems it is not working. is their something wrong ?  double area1=Math.abs(Imgproc.contourArea(tempContour));
            RotatedRect rect1=Imgproc.minAreaRect(newMat);
            double area2=rect1.size.width*rect1.size.height;
            appendLog("Math.abs(area1-area2);"+Math.abs(area1-area2));
            if(Math.abs(area1-area2)<100){